The set of values of $a$ for which the function $f(x)=(a^2-3a+2)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+(a-1)x$ possess a critical point

The set of values of $'a'$ for which the function $f(x)=(a^2-3a+2)\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+(a-1)x$ possess a critical points
The set of values of $'b'$ for which the function $f(x)=(b^2-3b+2)\cos2x+(b-1)x+\sin2$ does not possess stionary points.
The set of values of $a\in\mathbb R$ for which the function $f(x)=(4a-3)(x+\ln5)+2(a-7)\cot\left({\dfrac{x}{2}}\right)\sin^2\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right), x\neq 2n\pi$ has critical points, is


Notes: (1) Definition of critical point given in my book $f'(x)=0$ or $f'(x)$ Does not exist
(2) Definition of stationary points given in my book is $f'(x)=0$

For first Question: $f'(x)=(a^2-3a+2)\left[\dfrac{-1}{2}\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)\right]+(a-1)$
Hence $f'(x)=0$ when $a=1$ and $\sin\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\dfrac{2}{a-2}$
Reason given in book is for $a=1$ our function is $f(x)=0$ so $a=1$ cannot be critical point
and for critical point $\left|\dfrac{2}{a-2}\right|\leq1$ hence $a\in(-\infty,0]\cup[4,\infty)$

For second Question my apporach: $f'(x)=-2(b^2-3b+2)\sin(2x)+(b-1)$
Hence $f'(x)=0$  when $b=1$ and $\sin(2x)=\left|\dfrac{1}{2(b-2)}\right|$
as we don't want stationary point so $\left|\dfrac{1}{2(b-2)}\right|>1\implies b\in\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{5}{2}\right)$ and for $b=1$ our function is $f(x)=\sin2$
MY doubt: as in previous question $a=1$ was not critical point because $f(x)=0$ so in this question $b=1$ should not be stationary point because $f(x)=\sin2$
So final answer must be $b\in\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{5}{2}\right)\cup\{1\}$ but given answer is $b\in\left(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{5}{2}\right)$ only

For third question $f'(x)=(4a-3)+2(a-7)\cos(x)$ Hence $f'(x)=0$ when $\cos(x)=\dfrac{4a-3}{a-7}$ so for critical point $\left|\dfrac{4a-3}{a-7}\right|\geq 1\implies a\in \left[\dfrac{-4}{3},2\right]$ but given answer is $a\in \left[\dfrac{-4}{3},2\right)$
My doubt: Why $a=2$ is exculuded?

Is the derivative wrong for part $a$ because you start with cosine and after the derivative, you have cosine?

@Moo oh I made mistake and now it is FIxed, Thanks.
